# extra action viewset doesn't see object permission. django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have extra action in my viewset:

```
    @action(
        detail=True,
        methods=["patch"],
        permission_classes=[IsModeratorOfThePageOwner]
    )
    def block(self, request, pk=None):
        self._block_page(pk)
        return Response(
            data={"detail": "Successfully blocked."},
            status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        )
```

Permissions_classes don't work. If I change the permission class to the has_permission class then everything is Okay. But If pass permissions classes with has_object_permission then It doesn't work.

My permission class:

```
class IsModeratorOfThePageOwner(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return bool(
            request.user_data
            and request.user_data.get("role") == "Moderator"
            and obj.owner_group_id == request.user_data.get("group_id")
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra actions are all only on level has_permission, no object passed to them.
So, you should change your permissions so that they have all the logic within has_permission lvl.
If you need to get the basic viewset object passed to your extra action (as I see you have detail=True), then you extract it from view by id(pk):

```
pk = view.kwargs['pk']
```